# How do I arrange a navigated photo captured with RNCamera to a different screen in grid form or gallery form(with specified rows and columns)

Tags: react-native

Please I need help on how to go about this in react native, I want to arrange navigated photo captured with RNCamera to a different screen in grid or gallery form(in rows and column). In the app I am able to   navigate back to camera for new photo, the new picture taken should navigate to the new screen and add up to the previously captured photo in a grid or gallery form(in terms of rows and columns). I want to be able to add up new photos  taken with the camera and navigated to the new screen in grid form or gallery form(rows and column)

Currently, I am able to navigate an image taken to the new screen and also able to navigate back to camera to capture a new one, how do I go about adding up more images to the new screen I navigate to, in order to get it in gallery form(rows and columns,).